# Разбить число на два значения

Tags: javascript

Дано число например 547 необходимо разбить его в таком формате 5 и 47

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const n = 547;
const s = String(n);
console.log(`${s[0]} ${s[1]}${s[2]}`);
```

Comment: Гениально просто)

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 547
n1 = n % 100
n2 = (n - n1 ) / 100
```